# preserving part of class with user-defined conversion operator

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a class that will be exactly like a bool, except raise an event when it changes. My problem is that using a user-defined conversion operator creates a whole new object and so I lose the event listeners list. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
public class ObesrvableBool
{
    public event EventHandler<bool> Change;

    public static implicit operator bool(ObesrvableBool c)
    {
        return c.val;
    }
    public static implicit operator ObesrvableBool(bool v)
    {
        return new ObesrvableBool(v); // I lose Change here
    }
    private bool val;

    public ObesrvableBool(bool v)
    {
        this.val = v;
    }

    protected virtual void OnChange(bool v) // Where to call this?
    {
        EventHandler<bool> handler = Change;
        handler?.Invoke(this, v);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Example:

```
ObesrvableBool b = new ObesrvableBool();
b = true;
b.Change += On_b_Changed;
b = false; // Nothing happens here
```

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve] to highlight your problem. *When* do you lose the handlers?

Comment: You're going from a `bool` to an `ObservableBool` so you have no event listeners to lose. Just maintain your `ObservableBool` object the whole way through.

Comment: @nvoigt added an example

Comment: @itsme86 How do I do that?

Comment: Saying `b = false` is creating an entirely new instance of your observable, that's why you are losing the event.

Comment: @DavidG I know that. I want a solution / workaround

Comment: There isn't a solution that does what you want here really. You would have to create a method/property in your class to set the value.

Comment: deleted my working solution. good luck

Comment: @DetectivePikachu There were two bugs too obvious to require testing, plus the public event handler had been made private, which clearly couldn't work with OP's clearly illustrated use case. A infinitely-recursing getter is not working code. A working solution, with clear explanation of how it was to be used and why it was appropriate, would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind accessing your "observable" bool by MyBool.Value, then you could always have a class that exposes a Bool property, and have that property setter fire the change event.

```
public class ObservableBool
{
    public event EventHandler<bool> Change;

    private bool val;
    public bool Value
    {
        get { return val; }
        set
        {
            if (val != value)
            {
                val = value;

                var evt = Change;
                evt?.Invoke(this, val);
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableBool(bool v)
    {
        this.val = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a huge quibble, but if you're using the `?.` operator to raise the `Change` event, there's no need to copy `Change` to a local. `Change` is evaluated only once in that idiom.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I actually realized that as I typed it but force of habit, I remember the old pre-? days where you had to store the event in a local var before checking null to avoid some type of race condition. Thanks :)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I copied it from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/ (first example on that page). I didn't know about the evaluted-once thing

Comment: @Baruch Can't fault you for using MS docs, and what you've got is safe, but you'll also find [this example from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event), which isn't safe. This next article conveys (and better yet, *explains*) [the current thinking](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/): If you've got `?.`, use `MyEvent?.Invoke(this, args);`. But as I said, the only danger of the idiom you've got is it might attract pedants.